# Improve FN Keys and Touchpads on Windows Laptops

Tags: windows, software-rec, touchpad, fn-key

Is there software that improves the `fn` keys and touchpads on Windows laptops?

I'm sick of the inconstancy and the bugginess. it'd be nice to have some open source software to make it a better experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be wanting to *remap* the Fn key.

http://www.autohotkey.net/~daonlyfreez/tutorials/3p/Veil/fnkey.htm

Maybe you simply want to change the sensitivity of your touchpad. Please explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Basically, I want a nice consistent experience across computers. The stuff technically works, but what I'd like is for better graphics when pushing the fn keys (volume up graphic that appears on screen), and using special functions on the touchpad (like two-finger-scrolling (icon shows up)).

Comment: Ah, yes a richer user experience. Sounds like you are after a Hot Key manager with overlays like ones made by [Softarium](http://www.softarium.com/activekeys/) or [AgataSoft](http://download.cnet.com/AgataSoft-HotKey-Manager/3000-2084_4-10910950.html), but newer and nicer

Comment: Those look promising, I'll check 'em out and come back to mark this as answered if they're what I'm looking for. Thanks.